# Sound problem after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 (JABRA Evolve 65)

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio

I needed to post a question here since after numerous Google searches and attempts I couldn't solve this problem. So here's my problem:

My system consists from a PC computer with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, GeForce GTX 1080 Ti and three displays connected. I'm using JABRA Evolve 65 headphones (connected via USB cable to PC) for my sound output and after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 (clean install) I haven't been able to fix my sound issues (in 16.04 everything worked fine).

When I listen to, say a Youtube video, I can hear the sound but it is breaking up a lot, like it would have a lot of interference or something. Occasionally the sound is ok like 2-3 seconds and then again it starts breaking up again a lot. It sounds like someone would be pausing the sound and then very quickly turning it back on. That is, if you look at a Youtube video and press and hold space, that's almost identical to what my sound problem is like.

I have tried changing the default sample rate from 44.1kHz to 48kHz in the pulse daemon.conf, but this did not help me.

Any ideas what I could do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem solved! I recently asked another question regarding my hugely growing log-files in Ubuntu 18.04.

You can see the post here: [Huge syslog, syslog.1 and kern.log files stored in /var/log in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1165857/109991)

My log files were hugely growing in size (for reasons unknown yet to me) causing my system to freeze in the end. After I removed the huge log files I got my system back and running.

I later noticed that the log-files kept growing all the time from `AER pcieport`-messages (more info on the post above). I then found a solution from another site (also added to the above post) and tried it out. It worked and the log-files stopped growing. It then occured to me whether if the constant writing into the log-files affected the sound in my system.

I opened up a Youtube video and the problem was gone! So my sound problem was the result of constantly growing log-files.