# Huge syslog, syslog.1 and kern.log files stored in /var/log in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, log, pcie

I recently upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 on my PC (with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti GPU) and ever since my file system has been building up from these huge log-files. Every time I shut down my computer I get an endless number of pcieport-messages until some time the PC shuts itself down.

Yesterday I left my machine on for the night and when I came back to it there was a notification that disk space is all used up, that is `/dev/sda1` was in 100% use. I managed to find this out via `du`-command and pinpointed the problem to log files in `/var/log/`-folder, which contained log-files of more than `350GB`.

Currently, the log files are building up again and now they take up space approximately `150GB`. The log files that are causing the problem are: `syslog.1, syslog` and `kern.log`

**My question is: What is causing this problem and how to fix it?**

I have listed below information about my system and few lines from the log files. I will remove them again, but endlessly removing them does not seem the best long term solution.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

nvidia-smi
Thu Aug 15 09:25:53 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.40       Driver Version: 430.40       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 24%   58C    P0    67W / 250W |   1373MiB / 11177MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1298      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            89MiB |
|    0      1337      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          50MiB |
|    0      2258      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           726MiB |
|    0      2465      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         189MiB |
|    0     14914      G   ...e --type=gpu-process --field-trial-hand   154MiB |
|    0     18206      C   /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin     137MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

lspci -vt
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-01.0-[01]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
           |            \-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation Device 3e92
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
           +-1b.0-[02]--
           +-1c.0-[03]--
           +-1c.4-[04]----00.0  ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 2142
           +-1c.7-[05]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           +-1d.0-[06]--
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
           +-1f.4  Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
           \-1f.6  Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
```

> syslog.1

```
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680132] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680135] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680135] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680136] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680187] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680190] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680190] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680191] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680281] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680284] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680284] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680285] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680374] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680378] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680379] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680380] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680586] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680590] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680591] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   10.680591] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr
```

> syslog

```
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.590656] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.590836] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.590841] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.590843] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.590844] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591125] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591134] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591135] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591136] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591414] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591419] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591420] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591422] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591607] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591614] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591616] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591617] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591896] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 15 09:04:23 user kernel: [  307.591901] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
```

> kern.log

```
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219257] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219259] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219260] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219260] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219443] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219448] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219448] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219449] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219714] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219717] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219718] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219718] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219916] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219922] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219923] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.219924] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.220101] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.7
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.220104] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.220105] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:   device [8086:a297] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 14 10:14:03 user kernel: [   11.220105] pcieport 0000:00:1c.7:    [ 0] RxErr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem solved (I think) already by using the instructions here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173

> WORKAROUND: add pci=noaer to your kernel command line:
>
> (1) edit /etc/default/grub and and add pci=noaer to the line starting
> with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. It will look like this:
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
>
> (2) run "sudo
> update-grub"
>
> (3) reboot

After implementing these steps, I don't get the `pcieport`-messages anymore after shutting down my system and the log files stopped hugely growing in size.

However, I don't know if this fixed the root cause of the error-messages...

Comment: If you are still facing the issue, see https://itsfoss.com/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected/