# System crashes after running out of space because of giant log files (repeated WiFi error messages in syslog and kern.log)

Tags: kernel, iwlwifi

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on a Lenovo ThinkPad P52s. The system crashes after running out of space because of giant log files (syslog and kern.log) which have the same message repeated over and over. I can recover when this happens but it happens about once every two days.

Some system info and the repeated log messages are further below. I've seen a similar [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165857/huge-syslog-syslog-1-and-kern-log-files-stored-in-var-log-in-ubuntu-18-04) but the [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173) there seems specific to PCI issues.

System

```
lspci -vt
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620
           +-04.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
           +-08.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
           +-1c.0-[02]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GP108GLM [Quadro P500 Mobile]
           +-1c.6-[04]----00.0  Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
           +-1d.0-[07-3f]----00.0-[08-3f]--+-00.0-[09]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016]
           |                               +-01.0-[0a-3e]--
           |                               \-02.0-[3f]----00.0  Intel Corporation Device 15c1
           +-1d.2-[40]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
           +-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
           \-1f.6  Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
```

```
 lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:5914] (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9d10] (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #7 [8086:9d16] (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:9d18] (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d1a] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E [8086:9d4e] (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V [8086:15d8] (rev 21)
02:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108GLM [Quadro P500 Mobile] [10de:1d33] (rev a1)
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
07:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] [8086:15c0] (rev 01)
08:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] [8086:15c0] (rev 01)
08:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] [8086:15c0] (rev 01)
08:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] [8086:15c0] (rev 01)
09:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] [8086:15bf] (rev 01)
3f:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15c1] (rev 01)
40:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981 [144d:a808]
```

Message in syslog:

```
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508515] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508515] wlp4s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x0
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508531] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 3999 at /build/linux-hwe-kftZ87/linux-hwe-5.3.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:19 drv_sta_state+0x165/0x400 [mac80211]
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508532] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac bnep mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass nls_iso8859_1 iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd snd_hda_codec glue_helper snd_hda_core intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_hwdep iwlwifi joydev serio_raw intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof nouveau snd_pcm cfg80211 i915 uvcvideo mxm_wmi ttm v4l2_common mei_me videobuf2_vmalloc mei videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common intel_pch_thermal btusb videodev btrtl thinkpad_acpi btbcm btintel nvram drm_kms_helper ledtrig_audio bluetooth mc drm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event i2c_algo_bit ecdh_generic fb_sys_fops input_leds ecc snd_rawmidi syscopyarea intel_xhci_usb_role_switch processor_thermal_device sysfillrect roles sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf ucsi_acpi
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508547]  snd_seq typec_ucsi typec snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage psmouse nvme e1000e thunderbolt nvme_core wmi video
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508554] CPU: 3 PID: 3999 Comm: kworker/u16:2 Tainted: G        W         5.3.0-61-generic #55~18.04.1-Ubuntu
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508555] Hardware name: LENOVO 20LCS1FP00/20LCS1FP00, BIOS N27ET38W (1.24 ) 11/28/2019
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508565] Workqueue: phy0 ieee80211_csa_connection_drop_work [mac80211]
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508575] RIP: 0010:drv_sta_state+0x165/0x400 [mac80211]
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508576] Code: 85 c9 75 e3 e9 56 ff ff ff 49 8b 87 50 04 00 00 49 8d b7 70 04 00 00 48 c7 c7 70 a9 02 c1 48 85 c0 48 0f 45 f0 e8 1b 20 0f c0 <0f> 0b 41 bd fb ff ff ff e9 28 ff ff ff 41 83 fc 02 0f 85 82 00 00
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508577] RSP: 0018:ffffbf02846bfcb8 EFLAGS: 00010286
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508578] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff976d766f87a0 RCX: 0000000000000006
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508578] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: ffff976d7f2d7440
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508579] RBP: ffffbf02846bfcf0 R08: 0000000018dd1d35 R09: 0000000000000004
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508579] R10: ffffbf02846bfc48 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000004
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508580] R13: 0000000000000003 R14: ffff976d766f8d60 R15: ffff976d752da8c0
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508581] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff976d7f2c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508581] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508582] CR2: 000020120be3f000 CR3: 000000036a20a005 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508582] Call Trace:
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508593]  sta_info_move_state+0x284/0x360 [mac80211]
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508603]  __sta_info_destroy_part2+0x36/0x1a0 [mac80211]
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508613]  __sta_info_flush+0x139/0x1b0 [mac80211]
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508625]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0xc4/0x5d0 [mac80211]
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508627]  ? _raw_spin_unlock_bh+0x1e/0x20
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508637]  __ieee80211_disconnect+0x80/0x110 [mac80211]
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508646]  ieee80211_csa_connection_drop_work+0x15/0x20 [mac80211]
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508648]  process_one_work+0x1fd/0x3f0
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508650]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508652]  kthread+0x121/0x140
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508653]  ? process_one_work+0x3f0/0x3f0
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508654]  ? kthread_park+0xb0/0xb0
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508655]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508656] ---[ end trace e61bfaa0ebc904c6 ]---
Jun 27 12:58:48 torres kernel: [ 7483.508663] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

The message in kern.log is similar.

Searching for AER in logs.

```
grep -i AER /var/log/syslog*
/var/log/syslog.1:Jun 23 09:26:36 torres kernel: [    0.595197] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [AER]
/var/log/syslog.1:Jun 23 09:27:27 torres kernel: [    0.591256] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [AER]
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `lspci -nn`, and `grep -i AER /var/log/syslog*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I've added this info. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @heynnema I've update the BIOS but I'm still seeing the issue. I've edited the question to include the most recent version of the syslog after a crash.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live 20.04 DVD/USB and see if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

You have BIOS N27ET35W (1.21 ), dated 04/30/2019

There's a newer BIOS available, version (1.24 ), dated 12/19/2019, and can be downloaded [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p52s-type-20lb-20lc/20lc/20lcs1fp00/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI).

Note: Make sure I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Note: No guarantee that this will fix your problem, but it's a first step.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this in the next day or so.